# Why does my jquery $.get() not display any response

Tags: jquery

here's my shop.html snippet:

```
<li><a id="linkShop" href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
<div id="paneMiddle"></div>
```

and here's my main.js snippet:

```
$("a[id=linkShop]").click(function(){
    $.get("data1.html", function(response){
        $("div[id=paneMiddle]").html(response);
        alert("hi"+ response);
    }); 

});
```

data1.html has this content:

```
<p>data 1 - test</p>
```

i really don't know why this happened now, i've tried $.get in php before,
but now, i'm trying to use jquery w/ jsp, running in tomcat server.
idk why nothing goes out in my $.get() function.

help me..pls... T.T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not canceling the click event's default action on the clicked link so when you click the link, you'll just reload the page before the $.get gets any response.

Try

```
$("a[id=linkShop]").click(function(){
        $.get("data1.html", function(response){
                $("div[id=paneMiddle]").html(response);
                alert("hi"+ response);
        });     
        return false;
});
```

or

```
$("a[id=linkShop]").click(function(evt){
        $.get("data1.html", function(response){
                $("div[id=paneMiddle]").html(response);
                alert("hi"+ response);
        });     
        evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks. this worked. the alert appears. but the response does not appear in the div w/ id=paneMiddle. :(

Comment: Does it work if you refer to it with $('div#paneMiddle') instead?

Answer (score 0):

how about not using an < A > tag as your click target .. maybe just use a span instead ?

```
<li><span id='linkShop' style='cursor:pointer'>shop</span></li>
<div id="paneMiddle"></div>
```

and then simply

```
$("#linkShop").click(function() {
    $("#paneMiddle").load("data.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cancel the default action of your link with event.preventDefault:

```
$("a[id=linkShop]").click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.get("data1.html", function(response){ 

                $("div[id=paneMiddle]").html(response); 
                alert("hi"+ response); 
        });      
});
```

You can test live your script [here](http://jsbin.com/ojeyu/edit), and you can modify your ajax loaded content [here](http://jsbin.com/ubera/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$("a#linkShop").click(function(){
    $.get("data1.html", function(response){
            $("div#paneMiddle").html(response);
            alert("hi"+ response);
    });
```

});